# How can I set retry count to 0 by default for all Hangfire jobs?

Tags: hangfire

I am using C# ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Hangfire to schedule background jobs. By default if an exception occurs during the execution of the background job, there are 10 retry attempts. I am aware it is possible to use the `AutomaticRetry` attribute to set that to 0, but I don't want to do that on every single background job. Instead I want the default to be 0 and to only specify it manually with the attribute in the very very rare case that I want it to be non-0. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to do it like this in .Net Classic, I guess it should not be so different in .Net Core

```
// disable automatic retry if a job fails
Hangfire.GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute() { Attempts = 0 });
```

Comment: Will AutomaticRetryAttributes on the methods override this behaviour, though?

Comment: @Tri-EdgeAI No.

Comment: @Tri-EdgeAI to achieve this goal, you need a slightly different approach where you set up a custom filter provider which adds the AutomaticRetry attribute if and only if there isn't one already present.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70334037/1236044

Answer (score 4):

On ASP.NET Core +(5, 6)... you can make this:

```
services.AddHangfire((serviceProvider, globalConfiguration) =>
    
    // ...
    globalConfiguration.UseFilter(new AutomaticRetryAttribute { Attempts = 0 });
    // ...
});
```